# Put a Rendered Django Template in Json along with some other items

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, django

Let's say there is a view it has a template linked to it and view passes some context date i.e. objects to template and template renders it and i got a rendered html in browser, just typical view,

```
# views.py

def view_name(request, params):
    objects = Object.objects.all()
    somevar = "something"
    request_id = 123456

    # Context to be passed on to template
    context = {'objects':objects}

    return render(request, 'appname/template.html', context)
```

But i don't just want rendered html i want the output in `JSON` as following format

```
{"somevar":"something","html":"rendered html coming from template.html ","request_id":"123456"}
```

so i can easily differentiate the html and other values if calling a view as AJAX

Please ask any questions if i can make it more clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`render_to_string()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) shortcut and [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


def view_name(request, params):
    objects = Object.objects.all()
    somevar = "something"
    request_id = 123456

    # Context to be passed on to template
    context = {'objects':objects}

    rendered_html = render_to_string('appname/template.html', context)

    return JsonResponse({
        "somevar": somevar,
        "html": rendered_html,
        "request_id": request_id
    })
```

Comment: how do i import i mean from which class or module `render_to_string()` ?

Comment: @HassanNaseer import statements are also in the answer, check it out.

Comment: not sure why am i getting `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'push'`

Comment: just after importing `render_to_string`

Comment: In documentation it says i can pass request object to this function but when i do ii get that request error mentions i need that request object in template to do things like `request.user` etc